# Servlet Thread Handling

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

My login servlet receives a request, and after responding sleeps 1 minute.

My goal is to allow two requests to have access, and if a third transaction arrives, it must waits until the either of the other threads completes their respective task.

My code checks for which threads are sleeping, and which aren't.
The problem I'm having is when a thread wakes it up, I want to be able to assign it a task. Do I need to poll or is there some way to synchronize? How do I approach this?

```
public class Home extends HttpServlet 
{
    static HttpSession ses;
    static List<Thread> homethread = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        ses = request.getSession();
        homethread.add(Thread.currentThread());
        for(Thread th : homethread)
        {
            if(th.getState()!=Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING)
            {
                System.out.println("This Thread is Not in Waiting State -> "+th.getName()+"Its State -> "+th.getState());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("A Thread Is In Waiting State -> "+th.getName()+"Its State -> "+th.getState());
            }
            System.out.println("Thread Details->"+th+"Thread State->"+th.getState().TIMED_WAITING);
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writter = response.getWriter();
        writter.println
        (
                "<!DOCTYPE html>" + 
                "<html>" + 
                "<body>" +  
                "<img src=\"C:\\Users\\surya-pt3101\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\Screenshot (1).png\">"+
                "<h1 style=\"text-align:center;\">Provide Your Choice</h1>"+
                "<form action=\"Upload\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">" + 
                "<div style=\"text-align:center\">Upload File     :<input type=\"file\" name=\"UploadedFile\" multiple/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\"><br><br>"+
                "</form>" + 
                "<div style=\"text-align:center\">View Files     :<input type=\"submit\" formaction=\"View\" formmethod=\"post\" value=\"View\"/><br><br>" + 
                "<div style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"submit\" formaction=\"LogOut\" formmethod=\"post\" value=\"LogOut\"/>" + 
                        "</body>" + 
                        "</html>"
        );
        response.flushBuffer();
        try 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(60000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already written some code you could share?

Comment: I'd just respond back with a 4xx code and maybe a message like "try back in x seconds"

Answer (score 0):

Servlets must be thread safe by definition. Tomcat (or any other servlet container) internally contains a pool of threads that will execute your requests. So I don't see much sense in generating you own threads (of course if we are talking about not really tough computations). To make you class thread safe there are a few options: common synchronization methods (like synchronized/wait/notify) or more high-level structures (see java.util.concurrent package). Other shared not thread-safe objects, like ArrayLists, should be avoided. As I understand, you want to execute no more than 2 threads in a same time. You wrote "3rd Request Have to be Processed in the Completed Thread" - it seems for me that it is not reasonable if you are able to execute all needed computations in your servlet threads.
Bellow there is a snippet that uses java.util.concurrent.Semaphore - class that allows processing only 'n' threads in a time, where n is a number of permits.

```
public class Home extends HttpServlet {

  private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);

  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      try {
          semaphore.acquire();
          // Do what you need
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } finally {
          semaphore.release();
      }
  }
}
```

**UPD: Loader example**

Lets imagine that you have a form with a field and submit button. On click, some long action is expected, thus you want to show user a loader gif.

Part of html file:

```html
    <form>
      <label for="content">Enter value:</label>
      <input id="content" type="text" name="content">
      <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">Send</button>
      <img id="loader" style="display:none" src="../static/img/loading.gif">
    </form>
```

JS (using jQuery):

```js
    function sendRequest(content) {
      var payload = {};
      payload.content = content;
      return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '/your-endpoint',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload)
      })
    }

    $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
      $('#loader').show();
      $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
      const response = sendRequest($('#content').val());
      response.then((result) => {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#content').val("");
        alert(result);
      }).catch(error => {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#content').val("");
        alert(error);
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Anton i previously tried the same thing using synchronized block but if 3rd user request the URL i want their page to display a gif like (Processing) and soon after the completion of any  of the previous 2 threads i want to give the response to the 3 rd user automatically (i.e) without refreshing.

Comment: Hi @s.suryaPrakash. It is easy to implement with that semaphore scheme on backend and JS on frontend. Each user sends request, gif is displayed and when response from server comes (no matter immediately or after minute), gif is substituted with the received content. Only one request is needed. This behavior can be easily implemented using JQuery for example. Write if you need an example of code

Comment: Yeah i Understand but it's so helpful if i get some example code.@Anton Shelenkov Thanks in Advance